# Cut apart cube with text

Tags: modifiers

I'm looking to make a jigsaw puzzle to be 3d printed. I'm making a cube that is 22cmx10cmx4mm and putting text on it and extruding it out 1.5mm from the surface of the cube. I then join the text and the cube making one object.

I have tried appending a jigsaw mesh and a boolean modifier to cut through the complete piece into jigsaw puzzle pieces but it's not working. It either doesn't cut through properly or it only saves half of the text and inverts the rest. I have tried both difference and intersect boolean modifiers. Intersect gets rid of the base and difference keeps the base but not all of the text.

Is there a way to divide a cube into puzzle pieces keeping the text on top of it?

Answer (score 2):

If I got what you mean, it's not easy, but it can be done, imho.

But you have to be willing to do some retopology, because you need text mesh (blender always creates this from font object with bad topology) and booleans, two times (produces bad topology)...

first, experiment with a little cube base and a single letter, trust me.

1. create the box base and text mesh and ensure it has good topology (all quads, no doubles, a good mesh)

[image]

2. boolean "union" of the box and the text.

[image]

with more complex setups, it is a good idea to retolopogize the applied union result (all quads, no doubles, a good mesh) - optional but suggested

3. create the jigsaw pieces, as a single object but separated islands, ie: the pieces.  (again, ensure all quads, no doubles, a good mesh), and scale this mesh to make its bounds to "surround" the previous base+text union.

[image]

seeing this in transparency:

[image]

4. boolean "intersection" of the base+text with the "surrounding" jigsaw mesh (see settings on the right)

[image]

which gives you

[image]